# Populating new table with values from another table based on foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a SQL Server database connected to QGIS. I am using SQL Server Management Studio, trying to fill in columns in a new table with values from another table. I know that it is better practice to create a view, but when I attempt to load a view into QGIS, it returns the following error message:

```
Layer is not valid: The layer dbname='MBA-LBA_Ornaments' 
host=DESKTOP-DLA7UV8 estimatedmetadata=true 
srid=4326 type=Point disableInvalidGeometryHandling='1' 
primaryKeyInGeometryColumns='0' table="dbo".
"GoldWeight" (Geo4) is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map.
Reason: No primary key could be found on table GoldWeight
```

The only workaround I can come up with is to create a new table incorporating fields from the Ornaments table and the Sites table. Here is the structure of the relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ornaments](
    [OrnID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrnForm] [varchar](20),
    [OrnSubtype] [varchar](20),
    [FragmentYN] [char](1),
    [Material] [varchar](30),
    [Period] [varchar](10),
    [Phase] [varchar](20),
    [BasisOfDate] [varchar](50),
    [SiteID] [smallint],
    [DiscContext] [varchar](20),
    [DiscYear] [varchar](10),
    [SingleFindYN] [char](1),
    [BrokenYN] [varchar](2),
    [DistortedYN] [char](1),
    [WeightG] [numeric](8, 2),
    [SpatialPrecisionRating] [char](1),
    [ImageYN] [char](1),
    [Comments] [varchar](500),

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sites](
    [SiteID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteName] [varchar](50),
    [SiteType] [varchar](50),
    [Region] [varchar](50),
    [CountyDistrict] [nvarchar](30),
    [Latitude] [decimal](11, 6),
    [Longitude] [decimal](11, 6),
    [Comments] [varchar](500),
    [Geo4]  AS (case when [Latitude] IS NOT NULL AND [Longitude] IS NOT NULL 
         then [geography]::Point([Latitude],[Longitude],(4326))  end),
```

The GoldWeight table was created using:

```
SELECT SiteID, SUM(WeightG) AS 'Weight'
INTO GoldWeight
FROM Ornaments
WHERE Material = 'gold'
GROUP BY SiteID
```

I then added columns SiteName and Geo4 using:

```
  ALTER TABLE GoldWeight
        ADD SiteName VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
            Geo4 geography NULL
```

and added a foreign key using:

```
ALTER TABLE GoldWeight
ADD FOREIGN KEY (SiteID) REFERENCES Sites(SiteID)
```

I thought adding a foreign key would populate the fields, but of course that is not true. Is there a way to populate the SiteName and Geo4 fields with the appropriate data based on the SiteID foreign key relationship?

Comment: Why?  You can just lookup this information using a `JOIN`.  Copying the data in means that it gets out-of-date if the site table is updated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to put the information into a table because it is being exported into QGIS, which will not render views. I know that it is not ideal, but it is the only workaround I have been able to find. I have updated the question with this information.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that QGIS can't read from a view? To all intensive purposes, for the consumer, a view is a table i.e. `select * from MyTable` vs `select * from MyView` - the calling context shouldn't know the difference.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the down vote arrow you will see the reasons that people downvote, lack of research, lack of clarity and lack of usefulness. Your question has certainly improved, but originally it was hard to know what you wanted, and there was no attempt (which is part of research effort).

Comment: There is no question in this post. You seem to be saying there's also an answer in it, but it's not clear what that is either, and if so it doesn't belong in your post, it belongs in an answer post. Also your text re downvoting doesn't belong in your post either. Use a comment or post to [meta] but please reasearch. But what you have written is implicit as part of site usage, so it would serve no purpoe as a comment. Also that code doesn't seem minimal. [mre] Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete and/or flag comments no longer needed. [ask] [help] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0):

This query should serve the purpose, however copying the data to the referencing table is not a good practice.

```
UPDATE G
SET G.SiteName = S.SiteName,
    G.Geo4 = S.Geo4
FROM GoldWeight G
INNER JOIN SITES S ON S.SiteID= G.SiteID
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out an answer, which is to select the results from a view into a new table using:

```
SELECT dbo.GoldWeight.SiteID, 
   dbo.GoldWeight.Weight, 
   dbo.Sites.SiteName, 
   dbo.Sites.SiteType, 
   dbo.Sites.Region, 
   dbo.Sites.CountyDistrict,
   dbo.Sites.Geo4
INTO GoldWeight2
FROM   dbo.GoldWeight INNER JOIN
   dbo.Sites ON dbo.GoldWeight.SiteID = dbo.Sites.SiteID
```

then adding a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE GoldWeight2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (SiteID) REFERENCES Sites(SiteID)
```

then setting the SiteID column to NOT NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE
   QGIS_GoldWeight2
ALTER COLUMN
  SiteID smallint NOT NULL;
```

then setting SiteID as primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE QGIS_GoldWeight2
ADD PRIMARY KEY (SiteID);
```

I had to uncheck the box "Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation" under Tools > Options > Designer to successfully set the primary key.

It creates a table that QGIS can read, but the table will have to be deleted after import into QGIS because the data does not update if fields in the Sites table change.

Comment: You say that QGIS cannot select from the view because of no primary key? But you can always include the primary key of the base tables and/or combine them as required. Putting the results of a view into a table doesn't automatically give it a primary key. How does QGIS even know about the PK? Does it do a meta lookup first?

Comment: Add this comment + the error to your question

Comment: @DaleK I tried it with an earlier view--it shows up in QGIS browser panel successfully, but when dragged and dropped onto the map, it returns this error: "Layer is not valid: The layer dbname='MBA-LBA_Ornaments' host=LAPTOP-FLAV856G srid=4326 type=Point disableInvalidGeometryHandling='1' primaryKeyInGeometryColumns='0' table="dbo"."Orn_View_spatial" (Geo4) is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason: No primary key could be found on table Orn_View_spatial." Since QGIS is directly connected to SQL Server through QGIS browser panel, I assume it  that connection incl. PK info(?)

Comment: I recommend posting this question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/ because I can see its been an issue before and I expect its been solved, in an easier fashion before. The [first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225829/ms-sql-layer-invalid-layer-error-when-attempting-to-load-a-table) appears to indicate a workaround.